# Rig Not Working Properly

Tags: modeling, rigging, rigify

[image]

I have more or less finally rigged this character. However one of the gloves will not move (not a huge issue as I can work around this in the animation) however, the shoes are not working properly.

When I move one shoe, the other moves and warps slightly with it! As shown in the image below. I have tried separating them in edit mode as loose parts but I am not sure how else to go about this. I don't really want to have to start again with the rigging process!

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: should be there now cheers

Comment: you need to give us the address  ;)

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5944" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5944/)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your boots are parented to bones that they are not supposed to. The simplest way to fix it is to select them in *Edit* mode, then in the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Vertex Groups* > on the right of the vertex groups list, click on *Remove from All Groups* so that this part of the mesh won't be controlled by any bone. Now, keep your armature in *Pose* mode, select your object, go in *Weight Paint* mode, select the bone to which the boot is supposed to be linked and paint the boot with a brush in *Blend* > *Mix* mode.

[image]

Comment: im not sure how to keep my armature in pose mode while selecting the object?

Comment: I tried it and it didnt work- not sure if i am doing something wrong as i havent used the brush before. the boot just keeps deforming as i move the leg